# Service Worker fails to build in typescript Create React App

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, service-worker

How do I add a service worker to an existing create-react-app project without re-bootstrapping it?

I've been working for a while on a typescript project bootstrapped with `create-react-app`. I'm not sure exactly how it was originally bootstrapped, but I've invested a significant amount of time into the project so re-bootstrapping it (deleting it and starting over) isn't really an option.

I want to add service worker functionality into the app. However I'm finding that no matter what files I edit, after I run `yarn build`, the file `build/service-worker.js` is the default auto-generated service worker that comes with workbox. I've tried creating and editing files `src/sw.js`, `src/sw.ts`, `src/service-worker.ts` and `src/service-worker.js`.

I can't find any reference in the documentation for which file I'm supposed to edit, or any config file to edit where I can specify that I want my service worker file to be compiled.

When the project is run (`yarn build` + `serve -s build -l 4000`), I can see that the service worker registration completes successfully (through `src/serviceWorkerRegister.ts` and the default service worker is loaded into the app. This is the same file found in `build/service-worker.js` and is auto-generated.